# Google Native Client, sending binary data from NACL to the frontend

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, google-nativeclient

How do I send binary data, e.g. `mp3/mp4` data back to the frontend ?

I know there are two ways of doing it: utilizing the sandbox filesystem provided by NACL and get the url at the frontend; passing the data through the `PostMessage()` using `VarArrayBuffer`. It would be great if someone could give me a simple example of how to pass the binary data through `PostMessage()`. There is a Pong example for NACl FileSystem API but I 'm kind of confused on how to retrieve the file location as url so that the frontend JS could get it through the message.

Here is what I have done so far, using the second method of passing data through `PostMessage()` and `VarArrayBuffer`:

- I successfully retrieved data from online mp4 file and stored it in a char vector `vector<char> outputBuffer`.
- Dumped the data into a new char buffer and create `VarArrayBuffer` to hold the data and pass it to the JS side

  ```
  char* binaryBuffer = new char[outputBuffer.size()];
  int increment = 0;
  for (vector<char>::iterator it = outputBuffer.begin(); 
       it != outputBuffer.end(); it++) {
       binaryBuffer[increment] = *it;
  }

  pp::VarArrayBuffer outBuffer(binaryBuffer);
  instance_->PostMessage(outBuffer);//instance_ is a NACL module instance
  ```

So, how should the JS side catch the array buffer? Is it through `message.data` or something else?

Comment: I don't see how the constructor of VarArrayBuffer should know about the size of binaryBuffer. I guess that your code compiles because the pp::Var::Var(const char* utf8_str) constructor that expects a null terminated UTF-8 string is called implicitly  (https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/peppercpp/classpp_1_1_var?hl=de#a24ae309e6e0335d2b16aab6039c231fa).