# How to get a sum of values in array in Google Native Client inside C++?

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, message, google-nativeclient

**In my HTML**
Let's say I have 2 input fields  with values 3 and 4:

```
<form onchange="reload()">
  <h2>Input:</h2>
  <input type="number" id="val1" name="val1" value="3">
  <input type="number" id="val2" name="val2" value="4">
  <br><br>
  <h2>Output</h2>
  <input type="text" id="out" name="out" value="untouched by C++"><br>
</form>
```

**In my JavaScript**
I get the two values and push them into an array like so:

```
Module = document.getElementById('module');
var msg = [];
msg.push(Number(document.getElementById('val1').value));
msg.push(Number(document.getElementById('val2').value));
```

Then I send it to my C++ file to process the message

```
Module.postMessage(msg);
```

**In my C++ file** [ *Here is where I am stuck.* ]
The code I have to handle the message is below

```
virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) {
  std::string message = var_message.AsString();
  pp::Var var_reply = pp::Var(message);
  PostMessage(var_reply);
}
```

The issue is that it handles a **string** [*actually it crashes if I my **msg** is of type of an array*].

What I want it to expect and accept is an **array** or an **object**.
Basically, something like this:

```
virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) {
  pp::Var var_reply =  var_message[0] + var_messgae[1]; // I expect this to be 3+4=7
  PostMessage(var_reply);
}
```

#### Can somebody help me figure out how to expect an array or an object from JavaScript inside my C++ so that I could calculate values together and send the result back to JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue I had. The best approach is to use an object and pass the values as a JSON object, so

**in JavaScript**

```
values = {
        "val1": Number(document.getElementById('val1').value),
        "val2": Number(document.getElementById('val2').value)
    };
msg = JSON.stringify(values);
Module.postMessage(msg);
```

Then handle the message and send the response back to JavaScript

**in C++:**

In the header you need to add **picoJSON** to handle JSON and **sstream** to work with **isstringstream**:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "picojson.h"
using namespace std;
```

then later in the code:

```
virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) {

        picojson::value v;

        // pass the message that was sent from JavaScript as a string
        // var_message.AsString() will be in form "{\"val1\":4,\"val2\":4}");
        // and convert it to istringstream

        istringstream iss2((string)var_message.AsString());

        // parse iss2 and extract the values val1 and val2
        string err = picojson::parse(v, iss2);

        int val1 = (int)v.get("val1").get<double>();
        int val2 = (int)v.get("val2").get<double>();

        // finally send the message and you'll see the sum in the JavaScript
        PostMessage( val1 + val2 );

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation hasn't been updated yet, but as of `pepper_29` there is now a `pp::VarArray` interface for accessing arrays.

You can see the header file for the new C++ interface [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/cpp/var_array.h).

Here's how you can use it (untested):

```
virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) {
  if (!var_message.is_array()) return;

  pp::VarArray array(var_message);

  // Do some stuff with the array...
  uint32_t length = array.GetLength();
  double sum = 0;
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
     pp::Var element = array.Get(i);
     if (element.is_number()) {
       sum += element.AsDouble();
     }
  }

  pp::Var var_reply(sum);
  PostMessage(var_reply);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i want to send a string array

```
var nativeArray = new Array();
nativeArray[0] = "Item 1"
nativeArray[1] = "Item 2"
naclModuleElement.postMessage(nativeArray)
```

and nothing gets called in the HandleMessage

Sending `nativeArray.length` works and shows '2' in NaCl side

After some investigation, i saw that there is no `AsArray()` function in `pp::Var` class

Only primitives are available

There is a class `pp:VarArrayBuffer` which could be used to send/recieve binary info.. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292425/google-native-client-sending-binary-data-from-nacl-side-to-the-frontend-javascr) could help (did not download the example posted in it though)

Comment: I already saw the the **pp:VarArrayBuffer** but couldn't understand how to work with it. Additionally, same as you I noticed that there is no "AsArray()". The saddest thing is a lack of examples.